# Was formatting my flash drive then I closed the process, now my flash drive isn’t showing up, what do I do?

Tags: usb-drive, disk-formatting

I was formatting my flash drive then I mistakenly closed it while still formatting, now my flash drive won’t show up anymore, what do I do?

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see it with the disks utility.  From there, you can make it format, what is probably the only partition.

Disks utility is part of the gnome-disk-utility package